# How can compare one item list with other item list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have two lists: one with information (List A) charge on their respective areas of work, and another list containing the area with reports (List B) waiting to be approved (approval workflow). Area -> Metadata Manager -> Individual or group. I need to compare the two areas in the workflow (List B) and a mail is sent to your respective Manager. What would be the best way to do this??

Ex (Workflow in List B):

IF (AREA(List_A) ==  AREA(List_B)) THEN

```
SENT EMAIL MANAGER(List_B) // Email extracted from List_A
```

END IF

Answer (score 0):

Although your requirement is unclear (you didn't say what kind of comparison you would want to do), I can say for sure that there is no OOTB way to compare two items for equality.
You have to resort to custom code (either managed or javascript) and retrieve the two items, then compare them according to some logic (eg. are they equal when all of their fields or just some of them contain the same value? keep in mind that obviously their IDs will always be different)

Comment: I have two lists: one with information (List A) charge on their respective areas of work, and another list containing the area with reports (List B) waiting to be approved (approval workflow).

Area -> Metadata
Manager -> Individual or group.

I need to compare the two areas in the workflow (List B) and a mail is sent to your respective Manager. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: @PAbloco I suggest that you edit your original question and add this piece of information. I would also include a detail of the fields in each list and the exact comparison that you need to perform (as it is still unclear to me)

Comment: MdMazzotti, the question was edited.